# ACL: How is `ImplicitMeta` rule interpreted?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In the official documentation of Access Control in Hyperledger Fabric: 
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/access_control.html

> ImplicitMeta policies aggregate the result of policies

How exactly is a rule of ImplicitMeta interpreted  `set-theoretically', when in conjunction with other rules ?

Example:

```
Policies:
  AndPolicy:
    Type:Signature
    Rule: "AND('Org1.Peer','Org2.Peer','Org3.Peer')"
  OrPolicy:
    Type:Signature
    Rule: "OR('Org1.Peer','Org2.Peer','Org3.Peer')"
  MetaPolicy:
    Type:ImplicitMeta
    Rule: "ALL OrPolicy"
```

If we set the rule for MetaPolicy as "ANY AndPolicy", is it equivalent to OrPolicy?

If we set "ALL OrPolicy", is it equivalent to AndPolicy?

The syntax of `ImplicitMeta` rule `<ALL|ANY|MAJORITY> <sub_policy>` suggests that the sub_policy is a *set* of elements, while the `Signature` rule syntax like `A and B and C` can express a *conditional expression*, not a set. 
Thus, the exact meaning of a combination of these two rules seems unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like I've found an answer, albeit incomplete.
Any corrections, supplements are welcomed.

> If we set the rule for MetaPolicy as "ANY AndPolicy", is it equivalent
>   to OrPolicy? If we set "ALL OrPolicy", is it equivalent to AndPolicy?

The short answer is No.

[Policies in Hyperledger Fabric](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/policies.html) page, 
which is not linked from anywhere for some unknown reason, gives us some suggestion.

More lengthy explanation:

```
# The lines below are just based on my conceptual understanding, 
# therefore they may have errors in details.
Channel:
  Groups:
    Application:
      Policies:
        M:             #-----------(1)
          Type: ImplicitMeta
          Rule: "ALL P"
      Groups:
        GroupA:
          Policies:
            P:         #-----------(2)              
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('SampleOrg.admin')"
        GroupB:
          Policies:
            P:         #-----------(3)
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "AND('SampleOrg.member')"
```

In the configuration above,

- (1) can be expressed as `/Channel/Application/M`.
- (2) can be expressed as `/Channel/Application/GroupA/P`.
- (3) can be expressed as `/Channel/Application/GroupB/P`.
- Let's see what (1) means.

  - Its rule is specified as `ALL P`, which should be interpreted as *ALL subpolicies of M must be satisfied.*.
  - But what are subpolicies?  This is the key of this answer: according to `policies.html`, **the `ImplicitMeta` policy selects *implicitly* the sub-groups of the group where it resides**. In this case, `M` resides in `/Channel/Application`, thus both (2) and (3), which are under that path,  are the subpolicies.
  - An `ImplicitMeta` rule specifies that all/any/majority of the rules must be satisfied.
    In the case above, `M` will be satisfied only if at least one admin and all members signed.